# (<unknown>): did not find expected node content while parsing a flow node at line 18 column 14 while running rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am trying to run old Ruby on Rails project on my machine (Ubuntu). I installed rvm *ruby* **1.9.3-p551** and *rails* **2.3.2**.
After installing bundler, gems n etc; I ran `rake db:migrate`.

I am getting the following error, please help me out.

```
user@iam:~/Desktop/practice/Application$ rake db:migrate 
rake aborted!
(<unknown>): did not find expected node content while parsing a flow node at line 18 column 14
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: almost certainly a syntax error in database.yml at line 18 (or thereabouts)

Answer (score -2):

I think rake version problem installed rake in your machine is probably not matching for running your Rakefile before run rake db:migrate check rake command on your machine

Comment: That makes no sense at all